# IPHONE - How to make a disclaimer?

Tags: iphone, ios4

my app is almost finished and since is for airline pilots I would like to add a disclamer (like an alert view...but more like a scroll view) that pop up as soon as they start the app and if they don't press ok I want to exit from the app. Any advice would be really appreciated. 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a UIAlertView — if you put a lot of text in it, it automatically scrolls.

If the user presses the "No" button, you need to just disable the app rather than exit — apps aren't allowed to exit unless the user presses the home button. You could pop up a modal view controller (with no way of dismissing it) with a message saying that the app cannot be used until the disclaimer is read and accepted.

Comment: thanks. Are you sure I can't just exit if the user press "no"? I've seen a similar app that does it. What method can I use to show the alert view as soon as the app will finish launching?

Comment: See [Apple's guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1561/_index.html). I've heard of apps getting rejected for doing that. For the latter question, look at the delegate methods on UIApplication, such as `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`.